# IOS (intcount + 1) = 5

Tags: objective-c

When i put a count 1 +1 i get a return of 5....
can anyone help me?
used to make couters like this all the time, but this one retuns weird outcomes....

```
load_count = (load_count +1);
NSLog(@"loadcount %d",load_count);
if (load_count == 0){
    load_count = 1;
}
if (load_count = (picture_count +1)) {
    load_count = 1;
}
```

load_count = int

picture_count = int pulled from a array (gives back the count of pictures an a array)

log outcome:

```
2013-03-14 12:04:44.325  loadcount 5
2013-03-14 12:04:47.977  loadcount 5
2013-03-14 12:04:50.800  loadcount 5
```

Comment: seems the issue is not in this piece of code.

Comment: Your question is not at all clear.. And you might need `if (load_count == (picture_count +1))` instead of `if (load_count = (picture_count +1))`  (See the `==`)

Comment: question is painful on the eyes..

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear, but I *think* you are trying to make `load_count` increment from `0` to `picture_count` and wrap around to `0` again?

If so this does it all:

```
load_count = (load_count + 1) % picture_count;
```